Harmonic Vectors from Isothermal Coordinates and Dupin's Theorem
Say we have a smooth parameterized toroidal surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For this surface, we know that there is a set of coordinates called isothermal coordinates ($u,v$) which satisfy the following:
$\nabla_s^2 u = \nabla_s^2 v = 0$
where $\nabla_s$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Furthermore, this coordinates define two vectors $\nabla_s u, \nabla_s v$ that satisfy the following:

$\nabla_s u \cdot \nabla_s v = 0$,

$\nabla_s v = \mathbf{n} \times \nabla_s u$

$| \nabla_s u | = | \nabla_s v | = \lambda$

$\mathbf{n} =  \lambda^{-2} ( \nabla_s u \times \nabla_s v) $


where $\nabla_s$ is the "surface gradient". $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit vector normal to $S$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar function. The surface gradient can be expanded as follows:
$\nabla_s f(u,v) = \partial_u f \nabla_s u  + \partial_v f \nabla_s v$,
I am trying to make a connection between the vectors $\nabla_s u, \nabla_s v, \mathbf{n}$ defined by the isothermal coordinates and Dupin's Theorem. This theorem says there is one system of orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_n$ defined as the following:
$\mathbf{u}_1 = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u_1}$, $\mathbf{u}_2 = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u_2}$, $\mathbf{u}_n = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial n}$
where $\mathbf{r}$ is a point on surface $S$, $u_1, u_2$ are coordinates along the lines of constant curvature of the surface $S$ with scale factors $h_1, h_2$ and $n$ (note that $\mathbf{u}_n = \mathbf{n}$) is the distance along the normal to the surface with a scale factor of $1$. Dupin's theorem states that these vectors satisfy the following:
$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_1}{\partial n} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_2}{\partial n} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_n}{\partial n} = 0$.
Additionally, given that $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2$ are orthogonal vectors, $\nabla_s$ is expanded as follows:
$\nabla_s f(u_1,u_2) = \partial_{u_1} f \frac{1}{h_1} \mathbf{u}_1 + \partial_{u_2} f \frac{1}{h_2} \mathbf{u}_2 $,
My questions:

The concept of a normal derivative $\frac{\partial }{\partial n}$ of a variable in a neighborhood along the normal of surface $S$ only makes sense if the variables $u_1,u_2, n$ parameterize the whole space enclosed by surface $S$, not just the surface $S$ itself. Is this correct?

If $u_1,u_2, n$ parameterize the whole volume enclosed by surface $S$, it means that the parameter $n$ defines infinitely many surfaces $S'$ nested inside the volume enclosed by $S$ that have mutually orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{u}_1', \mathbf{u}_2'$.

Are the coordinates $u_1,u_2$ on surface $S$ the same as the isothermal coordinates $u,v$? Which would imply that $\frac{1}{h_1^2} \mathbf{u}_1 = \nabla_s u, \frac{1}{h_2^2} \mathbf{u}_2 = \nabla_s v$?

Finding the isothermal coordinates $u,v$ on a surface $S$ would be equivalent to finding the parameterization $\mathbf{r}$ of the volume enclosed by S but simply evaluated on surface $S$?


